# VSTS git cherry picking and branch strategy

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-cherry-pick

In VSTS we use git cherry picking as recommended [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/git-branching-guidance#port-changes-back-to-the-master-branch) to port changes back to the master branch. In short, we do exactly as recommended on that page (VSTS GUI does step 1 automatically as part of cherry picking):

1. Create a new feature branch off the master branch to port the changes.
2. Cherry-pick the changes from the release branch to your new feature branch.
3. Merge the feature branch back into the master branch in a second pull request.

With this process, we need to ensure that we haven't missed cherry picking anything back to master. All release branch changes are *supposed* to be cherry-picked back to master. However, that step has been forgotten on occasion (it's bound to happen with a manual process). So we cover the potential gap by manually comparing release branches to master as part of our development lifecycle.

**The pain that we're feeling is that the branch comparison tools in the VSTS web app don't understand that a changeset in one branch has been cherry-picked back to another branch.** As a result, it takes a good bit of time to understand whether anything is out of sync.

**Is there a way of making the comparison tools understand that a changeset in one branch is the changeset that was cherry-picked to another branch?**

Ideally, this process would be done in the same interface, but we're open to other options.

Comment: How about check it in history? https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhTTGjAu7Xeeojy7b

Comment: Wouldn't that only show up on the side that already has items cherry picked into it? In that case we would manually have to note from the comparison which items are new and then go find them in the branch that receives the cherry picks. Not trying to coerce, just looking for a simple solution.

Comment: This is looking like the better option: http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2013/09/07/no-cherry-picking.html

Comment: You can post an answer if it can solve the issue.

Comment: In the link you provide it says "Use cherry-picking instead of merging so that you have exact control over which commits are ported back to the master branch. Merging the feature branch into the master branch can bring over release-specific changes you don't want in the master branch." Yet you say "All release branch changes are supposed to be cherry-picked back to master." If you want ALL changes from release in master (as we do in our company), you should/could just merge release into master instead and avoid the whole issue.